# ken burns pan/scan on bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a simple bootstrap carousel and added the ken burns effect using css from the following thread

[Ken Burns on Twitter Bootstrap Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089479/ken-burns-on-twitter-bootstrap-carousel)

things work fine with static images

When i get my images from a mysqli recordset loop, I set the first image to active with js, but the first image (only) does not change

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  <!-- set first slide and its indicator to active to make slideshow work-->
  $('.carousel-inner .item:first').addClass('active');
  $('.carousel-inner .item:first').addClass('inactiveUntilOnLoad');
  $(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");

  $('.item').removeClass('inactiveUntilOnLoad');

});
```

anyone tried this ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the .addClass code within the

$(document).ready(function () {});

and the

$('.item').removeClass('inactiveUntilOnLoad'); within the $( window ).load(function() {});